# How to calculate positive balance and negative balance as positive in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join

I wrote code to give me the CurrentBalance on Accounts that have been placed in a certain Hold Status.

The problem is:

- When they are PostPaid Accounts then  the Balance owing is in Positive Numbers.
- When they are Prepaid Accounts then the Balance owing is in Negative Numbers.

My code is as follows (doesn't give me any Prepaid Accounts):

```
SELECT A.[AccountId]
      ,AccountNumbe]
      ,AccountStatusId
      ,AccountTypeId
      ,CASE WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0100'
            THEN 'PrePaid'
            WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0200'
            THEN 'PostPaid'
       END PlanType
      ,CASE WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0100'
            THEN ABS([CurrentBalance])
        WHEN P.PlanCode = 'P0200'
            THEN [CurrentBalance]
       END CurrentBalance
      ,HoldStatusId
      ,D.Last_Change

  FROM [Account] A

  INNER JOIN  ( 
               SELECT AccountId
             ,MAX(Created) Last_Change
        FROM HoldHistory
        WHERE ToHoldStatusId IN (1,2,11)               
        GROUP BY AccountId
        ) D
        ON A.AccountID = D.AccountId

  INNER JOIN AccountPlan P ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId

  WHERE HoldStatusId IN (1,2,11)
    AND AccountStatusId IN (1,2)
    AND DATEDIFF (DAY, D.Last_Change, GETDATE()) > 180
    AND [CurrentBalance] > 25

  ORDER BY PlanType --CurrentBalance DESC, AccountNumber


--
```

But when I run this query, I get all PostPaid Accounts only. I don't get any Prepaid Accounts.

If I do:

```
AND ABS([CurrentBalance]) > 25  --instead of AND [CurrentBalance] > 25
```

then that may not work because Some PostPaid Accounts pay more than they are due to compensate for the next month's bill. That puts them in negative balance.

Any suggestions? Where is the error in my code?

Comment: If prepaid balances are negative, then I assume your "AND [CurrentBalance] > 25" condition eliminates them. Do you mean "AND ABS([CurrentBalance]) > 25"?

Comment: That may not work because some PostPaid Accounts have negative balance too since they sometimes pay extra (more than what they are due)

Comment: Okay, but is that condition the source of your problem? You can put whatever case statement you want in there. (You can put the same case statement from your SELECT clause into your WHERE ... > 25 clause if that's the criteria).

Answer (score 0):

PrePaid is negative and PostPaid is positive right ?

```
WHERE 
(
      (P.PlanCode = 'P0100' AND CurrentBalance < 25)
OR    (P.PlanCode = 'P0200' AND CurrentBalance > 25)
)
```

Comment: But the Total of the Current Balance would be inaccurate because the negative balance from Prepaid would negate the Positive Balance of PostPaid.

Comment: please post some sample data with expected result